# What parameter should be added to gitlab-ci.yml to extend the job log size (output_limit)?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm facing this issue when running my pipeline (unit tests particularly)
`Job's log exceeded limit of 16777216 bytes`.

I would like to know what parameter can be added to `gitlab-ci.yml` configuration to avoid having such an error.

I've tried the `mvn --quiet` option to make the log lighter but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using private runners?

It's configured per gitlab-runner - see option **output_limit** in
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

> output_limit  Set maximum build log size in kilobytes, by default set to 4096 (4MB)